# 2 of 4 cards for 1 die

Tags: mathematics, cards, dice

These are equivalent to using using a deck of 4 cards
                             to emulate a 6-sided die.

A.     Assign integer values to   *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*  
       so that the 6 possible 
  pairwise sums  
       *a+b*,   *a+c*,   *a+d*,  
       *b+c*,   *b+d*,   *c+d* 
  are   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  
       though not necessarily in that order.

B.     Same as above but with *noninteger* values
       for   *a*, *b*, *c*, *d* .

C.     Assign integer values from the range 0 through 6 
  to   *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*   so that
       the 6 possible pairwise *absolute*    
  *differences*   |*a-b*|,   |*a-c*|,   |*a-d*|,
                       |*b-c*|,   |*b-d*|,   |*c-d*|  
  are   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  
       though not necessarily in that order.  
  Two solutions.

Comment: Side note: In part C, eliminating the restriction to integers 0 through 6 would allow infinitely many solutions, all added the same amount, as with _a_ + kitchen-sink, _b_ + kitchen-sink, _c_ + kitchen-sink, _d_ + kitchen-sink .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A. Solution:**

> `0, 1, 2, 4` (hey there binary my old friend)

It should be obvious why this solution works.

**B. Solution:**

> `-0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5`

This is a simple transformation of the solution to A, and should also be obvious

**C. Both solutions:**

> `0, 1, 4, 6`

because

> |0 - 1| = 1,  |4 - 6| = 2, |1 - 4| = 3, |0 - 4| = 4, |1 - 6| = 5, |0 - 6| = 6

and

> `0, 2, 5, 6`

because

> |5 - 6| = 1, |0 - 2| = 2, |2 - 5| = 3, |2 - 6| = 4, |0 - 5| = 5, |0 - 6| = 6

Comment: Quick and clean, William Z! These puzzles are distillations of a wonderfully more convoluted 2-of-9-cards-for-2-dice puzzle at [ken.duisenberg.com/potw/archive/arch99/990416.html](http://ken.duisenberg.com/potw/archive/arch99/990416.html). The goal of that puzzle is to have the 36 pairwise sums of 9 values match the distribution of the 36 possible sums of 2 dice (1 way for sum=2, 2 ways for sum=3, ..., 6 ways for sum=7,  5 ways for sum=8, ..., 1 way for sum=12.)

Comment: @human That's interesting, thanks for sharing! These puzzles reminded me of one of [Simon Tatham](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/)'s articles: [A Pair Of Dice Which Never Roll 7](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/dice/)

Comment: @human How did you know he is William Z?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I removed outdated info from my SE profile today - and changed my name from the default when I did so.